# Internal Error in installing RubyGems (Beginner)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm a beginner at programming. I'm learning from a book and while reading the section on RubyGems, it told me to try and install a gem called feedtools. Using Mac, so I typed: sudo gem install feedtools (due to permission issue)

But then this long message appeared.

```
sudo gem install feedtools
Password:
Fetching: i18n-0.7.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed i18n-0.7.0
Fetching: thread_safe-0.3.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed thread_safe-0.3.5
Fetching: tzinfo-1.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed tzinfo-1.2.2
Fetching: minitest-5.9.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed minitest-5.9.0
Fetching: activesupport-4.2.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activesupport-4.2.6
Fetching: builder-3.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed builder-3.2.2
Fetching: activemodel-4.2.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activemodel-4.2.6
Fetching: arel-6.0.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed arel-6.0.3
Fetching: activerecord-4.2.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activerecord-4.2.6
Fetching: uuidtools-2.1.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed uuidtools-2.1.5
Fetching: feedtools-0.2.29.gem (100%)

FeedTool's caching schema has changed to allow Feed objects to be
serialized to the cache.  This should offer some limited speed up
in some cases.

Successfully installed feedtools-0.2.29
Parsing documentation for i18n-0.7.0
Installing ri documentation for i18n-0.7.0
Parsing documentation for thread_safe-0.3.5
Installing ri documentation for thread_safe-0.3.5
Parsing documentation for tzinfo-1.2.2
Installing ri documentation for tzinfo-1.2.2
Parsing documentation for minitest-5.9.0
Installing ri documentation for minitest-5.9.0
Parsing documentation for activesupport-4.2.6
unable to convert "\x84" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/active_support/values/unicode_tables.dat, skipping
Installing ri documentation for activesupport-4.2.6
Parsing documentation for builder-3.2.2
Installing ri documentation for builder-3.2.2
Parsing documentation for activemodel-4.2.6
Installing ri documentation for activemodel-4.2.6
Parsing documentation for arel-6.0.3
Installing ri documentation for arel-6.0.3
Parsing documentation for activerecord-4.2.6
Installing ri documentation for activerecord-4.2.6
Parsing documentation for uuidtools-2.1.5
Installing ri documentation for uuidtools-2.1.5
Parsing documentation for feedtools-0.2.29
unable to convert "\xA6" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/feed_tools/vendor/html5/testdata/encoding/chardet/test_big5.txt, skipping
unable to convert "\xEF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/feed_tools/vendor/html5/testdata/encoding/tests1.dat, skipping
Before reporting this, could you check that the file you're documenting
has proper syntax:

  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -c lib/feed_tools/vendor/html5/testdata/sites/web-apps-old.htm

RDoc is not a full Ruby parser and will fail when fed invalid ruby programs.

The internal error was:

(NoMethodError) undefined method `last' for nil:NilClass

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `last' for nil:NilClass
```

What does this mean? Do I have to uninstall the gem? How can I install it correctly? Sorry I'm new to this and I'm worried I might do something dumb in command to mess up and not recover.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is just an error installing the documentation for the gem, which isn't important really. You can tell RubyGems to skip installing documentation, and gems will install faster

Comment: I'd advise against installing ruby gems under sudo rights. Try using rbenv too, you won't run into permission errors as quickly as you install rubies in your own folder instead of under a root protected folder.
https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv

Comment: *Using Mac, so I typed: sudo gem install*--Don't use sudo.  Leave your system ruby alone.  Install your own ruby using rvm, rbenv, etc.  Then install gems into your own ruby, which does not require sudo.

Answer (score 0):

This error relates only to installing the documentation; you can bypass installing the offending documentation by installing it with this command:

```
gem install feedtools --no-ri
```

However, even with the error, the gem code itself did install successfully:

```
➜  ~   gem list feedtools

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

feedtools (0.2.29)
```

I am using `rvm` to manage my rubies in my Unix user space so that I don't need to use sudo.  This is why I did not specify `sudo`.   Like the others, I recommend using `rvm` or `rbenv`.